# connect with sftp in other ip(place) is wrong?

Tags: ftp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp

In aws ubuntu, I usely connect sftp in my home, connected well
but i try connect sftp in campus with the same laptop. The connection was interrupted due an socket error (# 10053 Software caused connecting abort)
Can you help me? please.